# Button in a list, how to make it ''edit'' the good line?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make list rows editable with a click button. The "edit" button should edit the line it matches with. Right now, the edit button only edit the first row.

It's for a little program I'm developping on node.js. HTML, CSS and Javascript is what I'm mostly using.

**Here's my HTML body:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="offer in offers|limitTo:5">

   <td><button onclick="editOfferInfos()">Edit</button></td>

   <td id="offerNamePostfix" class="offerNamePostfix">{{offer.namePostfix}}</td>
   <td id="offerUrl" class="offerUrl">{{offer.url}}</td>
   <td id="offerLimitEnabled">{{offer.capConfiguration.enabled}}</td>
   <td id="offerLimit">{{offer.capConfiguration.limit}}</td>
   <td id="offerTimeUnit">{{offer.capConfiguration.timeUnit}}</td>
   <td id="offerReplacementOfferId">{{offer.capConfiguration.replacementOfferId.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript Function:**

```
function editOfferInfos(){
  var x = document.getElementById("offerNamePostfix");
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text'>";

  x = document.getElementById("offerUrl");
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder={offer.url}}>";
  x = document.getElementById("offerLimitEnabled");

    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder={{offer.capConfiguration.enabled}}>";

  x = document.getElementById("offerLimit");
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder={{offer.capConfiguration.limit}}>";

  x = document.getElementById("offerTimeUnit");
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder={{offer.capConfiguration.timeUnit}}>";

  x = document.getElementById("offerReplacementOfferId");
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' placeholder={{offer.capConfiguration.replacementOfferId.id}}";
}
```

The button ''Edit Button'' should turn the matching line with textboxes. Right now, it is turning into textboxes only the first row, be it the first button, or the last one.

Comment: Instead of all this, just have a click of the button make the current row `contenteditible = true`. No new HTML needed.

Comment: So, maybe I am missing something, you are using an AngularJs ng-repeat, but you are not using any angular in the actual JavaScript? Not sure if you are able to or not, but if you can, try to use Angular, in that case you could simply have a variable in your model that says if it is editable that is changed on the button click and then have an *ngIf or something that could change the element for you based on that variable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Okay will try this ! Do you need to put this in the JS Function or directly in the HMTL <button> tag?

Comment: @dmoore1181 As you said, it could be easier with Angular in the script. I just don't really know much about this, since I'm really beginning. I'm mostly pasting and editing code and doing trial and error until it works. But I'm just stuck right now.

Comment: Your problem here is that you are using the "id" attribute on each of your `<td>`. Ids are supposed to be unique for the entire document, but you are repeating them on every row. So javascript grabs the first one. That is why you are only editing the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all this, just have a click of the button make the current row `contentEditible = "true"`. No dynamically created HTML needed.

```js
// Get all the "buttons" into an Array
let buttons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".edit > span"));

// Loop over the array
buttons.forEach(function(button){
  // Set up event handler
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Locate the editable cell in the current row and make that cell editible
    this.closest("tr").querySelector(".editible").contentEditable  = "true";
  });
});

// For resetting the cells after editing.....

// Get all the editible cells into an Array
let editibleCells = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".editible"));

// Loop over the array
editibleCells.forEach(function(cell){
  // Set up event handler
  cell.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    this.contentEditable  = "false";  // Turn off editable for the current cell
  });
});
```

```css
body { font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica; }
table, td { border:1px dashed #e9e9e9; padding:3px; }
.edit > span { display:inline-block; border:1px solid #e0e0e0; padding:5px; background-color:#d0d0d0; cursor:pointer; border-radius:3px; }
[contenteditable="true"] { background:yellow; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
    <td class="editible">Row 1, Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 3</td>
    <td class="edit"><span>Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="editible">Row 2, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 3</td>
    <td class="edit"><span>Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
    <td class="editible">Row 3, Cell 3</td>
    <td class="edit"><span>Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not how I thought I would do it, but actully, it's working pretty well ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I believe `contentEditable` does not work on `<td>` in IE or MS Edge. I ran into this little SNAFU in one of my projects, I ended up embedding a `<div>` inside the `<td>` that I could place the `contentEditable` on.

Comment: @bcr666 Good to know, but a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

So, since *Angular* isn't specified, I'm gonna give a general JavaScript solution.

First, let's add a class to every button to make sure `this` is bound to the correct button from javascript side of things.

Also make sure to add `.editable` class to every `td`

```html
<button class="click-trigger">Edit</button>

 <td  class="editable">{{offer.namePostfix}}</td>
   <td id="offerUrl" class="editable">{{offer.url}}</td>
```

Second, add the following js code:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger');

// Let's setup the event listeners
buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', editOfferInfos);

function editOfferInfos() {
   let clickedButton = this;
   /* then you can just use .querySelectorAll to swap the elements with editable items */
  clickedButton.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.editable').forEach( item => {
     item.innerHTML = "<input type='text'>"
  });
}
```